# Dividing authenticated and unauthenticated layouts in Rails with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-6

I just started a new Rails (6.0.0.rc1) application and included Devise for authentication. Now, Devise comes with a lot of views that are used for registration, sign in and so forth. Naturally I want to give unauthenticated users access to those views, while having the main application completely for authenticated users only. Currently I do the following in my `routes.rb`:

```
devise_scope :user do
  authenticated :user do
    root 'pages#home', as: :authenticated_root
  end

  unauthenticated do
    root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
  end
end
```

Then in my `application.haml` I have a simple if/else statement:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
  ...
  %body
    - if user_signed_in?
      = render 'some/template'
        = yield
    - else
      = yield
```

This seems like a hack to me though, also since it includes all files in the %head no matter if a user is logged in or not.

What would be the best way to define one kind of layout for unauthenticated users and one for logged in users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `routes.rb` looks fine to me.

To tell the application to use different layouts for the different devise controllers based on the authentication status of a user I have this in my `application.rb`:

```rb
# application.rb

module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.to_prepare do
      Devise::SessionsController.layout 'unauthenticated_application'
      Devise::RegistrationsController.layout proc { |_controller| user_signed_in? ? 'application' : 'unauthenticated_application' }
      Devise::ConfirmationsController.layout 'unauthenticated_application'
      Devise::UnlocksController.layout 'unauthenticated_application'
      Devise::PasswordsController.layout 'unauthenticated_application'
      Devise::InvitationsController.layout proc { |_controller| user_signed_in? ? 'application' : 'unauthenticated_application' }
    end
  end
end
```

So, additionally to the `application.html.slim` I created the `unauthenticated_application.html.slim` in the layouts folder.

Reference: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-custom-layouts

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

As the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionView/Layouts.html) state:

> You can either specify a layout declaratively (using the layout class method) or give it the same name as your controller, and place it in app/views/layouts. If a subclass does not have a layout specified, it inherits its layout using normal Ruby inheritance.
>
> For instance, if you have PostsController and a template named app/views/layouts/posts.html.erb, that template will be used for all actions in PostsController and controllers inheriting from PostsController.
>
> If you use a module, for instance Weblog::PostsController, you will need a template named app/views/layouts/weblog/posts.html.erb.

So, you just need to define your custom layout as `app/views/layouts/devise/sessions.html.erb`.